# Open my site with popup window

Tags: php, javascript, html

I just finished make a web application. But I want to open that application by popup window so there's nothing back button on the bar.

The flow is when we type my URL application, it's going to popup window. After then we can make a shortcut or bookmark that's page and when we click it, it's still opened in popup window.

I've tried the JavaScript code, but it's just when we click hyperlink in my application.When I'm typing an URL application, it's still not going smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try push your javascript popup code on body tag's onload event?

for example:

```
<body onload="popup_new_window()"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

put a script where you want to open a window as

```
window.onload()
```

There might be so many parameters which you want to put. Just google the window.onload property

Answer (score 0):

Alot of browser automaticaly block this thinks.

You can use something like:

```
$().ready(function(){  
   eval($('#el')).click());  
});
```

On a element set to the click function something like "openPopup()" and on ready open the popup!

​

```
<a​​ href='#asd' id='asd' onclick='openwindow()'>popup</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<script>
function openwindow()
{
window.open("http://www.yoursite.com",
    "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");
}

$().ready(function(){  
   $('#asd').click(function(){openwindow();});
   eval($('#asd').click());  
});​
</script>
```

Comment: eval? Really? Why would use use that. Yikes.

Comment: this method i have used sometimes to make works the function associated to the click event.

because the popup automati copened is blocked by the browser, in this way, was work for me to workaround this problem.

But this is old codeworked long time ago...
If user1819919 post some code, we can see a beter solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can not just have the page always open up without the toolbars. The browser does not work like that. Modern day browsers also show most of the toolbars you want to hide for security purposes.

Also opening it up in a pop up window onload is asking to be blocked by pop up blockers, plus you will be left with the original window.